# How to declare a generic interface with type extending two interfaces in kotin

Tags: generics, inheritance, kotlin, interface

I’m searching for an explanation of how to write an interface with the generic type T extending two interfaces Comparable and Serializable

```
Interface<K:Comparable<K>>
It should also be K: java.io.Serializable 
I want to know if it is possible in Kotlin programming language
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface MyInterface<K> where K : Comparable<K>, K : Serializable
```

Please see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/generics.html#constraints for details.